# Ubuntu: как выделить localhost дополнительный порт?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, localhost, сокеты, порты

Создал сокет на php, но он не работает, потому что порт localhost:8000, в котором я его хочу реализовать уже прослушивает php8.0-fpm. Как решить проблему? php-fpm нужен для nginx - никуда не денешься. Подумал о том, что у localhost вроде 3 порта есть доступных по умолчанию. Но информации про это не нашел. И если они есть, не знаю, какой у них номер. Сейчас у меня так: $socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://localhost:8080", $errno, $errstr);

Если нет портов кроме 8000, то как их создать в ubuntu? А может, это вообще по-другому решается?

Comment: У localhost 64 тысячи портов доступных по умолчанию… Выбирайте любое свободное число больше 1024

Comment: Портов tcp 65535 (два байта) на каждый из возможных ip. Затем один только loopback это 127.0.0.0/8 сеть = 16млн адресов. Только для портов меньше 1024 номера нужны привелегии рута.

Comment: @Мелкий все равно поставил так: $socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://localhost:2000", $errno, $errstr); если в адресной строке вбить: http://chut.local/index.php?dcdcdcd, то возвращает: Address already in use (0) . У меня сокет-сервер, который на любой запрос должен возвращать "Привет": fwrite($connect, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nПривет");

Comment: а какое отношение некий chut.local/index.php?dcdcdcd (вероятно http?) должен иметь к 2000 порту? Запустите скрипт с сокет-сервером и обратитесь к нему по tcp 2000 порту

Comment: @Мелкий chut.local/index.php?dcdcdcd - это домен в nginx, у меня же этот сервер пока в index.php по этому адресу... как же я запущу его в таком случае? Я делаю сервер как тут написано https://habr.com/ru/post/209864/ у него в примере $socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:8000", $errno, $errstr); я подставлю на место его значений свои в скрипте: stream_socket_server("tcp://localhost:2000", $errno, $errstr) Неправильно понимаю?

Comment: @Мелкий а ?dcdcdcd чтобы спровоцировать ответ сего сокет сервера, изуините, что может, чего-то не понимаю - новичок..